# How to install System updates in HTC ONE SU

Tags: updates, htc-desire, rom-flashing, htc

My handset HTC One Su (t528w) showing notification of system update to 4.1.1 from present 4.0.4 . When ever I click on install updates. it reeboted and log into bootloader menu . How can I install the updates ?

I searched on google but didnt get any help . This mobile I bought from China . So didnt find any useful help .

Comment: Where do you get the update notification?
I have the same phone and I don't know where to look for the notification.

Comment: @romanr9999 Settings>>About>>Software Updates >>Check now

if your network has someupdates for your mobile then after check you will get notification for upgrade.